# multi checkbox HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have a strange problem in passing multi checkbox values from HTML to PHP.

Here is the test.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Test Multi CheckBox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

foreach($_GET['currency'] as $currency)
{
  echo $currency."<br/>";
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form_individu" action="http://my-site.com/test.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="usd"/>USD
    <input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="euro"/>EURO
    <input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="cad"/>CAD
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Testing this function on my production server gives me the following URL :

```
test.php?currency%255B%255D=usd&currency%255B%255D=euro
```

and I can't output the currency values in PHP due to :

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line 14
```

But on localhost, the URL becomes :

```
test.php?currency%5B%5D=usd&currency%5B%5D=euro
```

and PHP can properly output currency values !

so the only difference is in URL encoding of currency[] :

```
-> currency%255B%255D on server
-> currency%5B%5D on localhost
```

What can explain this difference ? and how can I configure server to get it work ?

I hope I'm gonna learn something I don't know yet ... thanks to you guys :)

**EUREKA !**

the error comes from my .htaccess :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

# URL rewriting module activation
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#Redirection http:// vers http://www pour éviter le duplicate content
# LOCAL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.my-domain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
```

if I comment last two lines, code works. I figure it out thanks to the last post of [this article](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=77172). It appears brakets [] are rewritten and transforming %255B%255D into %5B%5D. So if someone is able to bring a solution, I'm still listening ...

Comment: why are you using get? you should use post instead...

Comment: Did you set the encoding to UTF-8 of your FILE?

Comment: Yes I set file encoding to UTF-8 and I also tried post but still same problem. I kept get on my example because that's what helped me to diagnose what the problem was !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's the character encoding you've defined for your document. You have it set to UTF-8, which is a 2-byte encoding. Try one of the LATIN character sets, like `ISO-8859-1` and see if that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly set the encoding to ISO does not help !

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the following code. It is working fine.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Test Multi CheckBox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

foreach($_POST['currency'] as $currency)
{
  echo $currency."<br/>";
}
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form_individu" action="/test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="usd" />USD
    <input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="euro"/>EURO
    <input type="checkbox" name="currency[]" value="cad"/>CAD
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Modifier</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```